# How to run combined findstr script

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

Hi I have a script I made using information on [this](http://www.dostips.com/?t=batch.findandreplace) page.

I realize that running two separate batch files (`:SetVar`and`:Brains`) will work but when I try to combine the two into one It doesn't work.

I'd be happy if anyone can explain to me why mine does not work and show me what I can do to make mine work.

```
:SetVar
Brains "Hello" "Goodbye" "input.txt" > "newfile.txt"
GOTO :Brains

:Brains
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.
)
PAUSE
```

When I use the Call command:

```
call :SetVar
call :Brains
goto :eof
pause

:SetVar
:Brains "Hello" "Goodbye" "input.txt" > "newfile.txt"
goto :eof

:Brains
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.
)
goto :eof
```

I get no error but I get:

```
C:\Users\MALKAVIAN\Batch files\change words in file>CALL :SetVar

C:\Users\MALKAVIAN\Batch files\change words in file>goto :eof

C:\Users\MALKAVIAN\Batch files\change words in file>CALL :Brains

C:\Users\MALKAVIAN\Batch files\change words in file>goto :eof

C:\Users\MALKAVIAN\Batch files\change words in file>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: What specifically "does not work"  ?

Comment: @geisterfurz007 - I would like to run the two scripts (in one `.bat` file instead of two) and have the same effect.

Comment: I understood that part, but what does the wrong effect look like? Does the programm do nothing, brings it up wrong results/different from the other version. Btw I am curious what the second line is supposed to do. I am not really into batch, so this might be a dumb question... You could try to place a call in front of that second line (not instead of `GOTO` but the line above)

Comment: Blank cmd prompt. I tried using the `call` command to call `:SetVa` and `:Brains` and i get press any key to continue but no errors

Comment: I ment as followed: In the first codeblock of your question you have this code: `Brains "Hello" "Goodbye" "input.txt" > "newfile.txt"` Try changing it to this: `call :Brains "Hello" "Goodbye" "input.txt"`  EDIT: I tested it and it echoes all lines from the input.txt. I am not sure if that is the desired outcome, but that is what it does with the change.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 - I get a infinite loop of `The system cannot find the path specified.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

Comment: Would you mind updating your question with the current code?

Comment: Sure if you think so! The code I have works for me. If you are not interested in an answer based on the age of the person answering you mind want to consider deleting this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this batch file :

I added a fourth argument to output the results of substitution in new text file :

***Edit***

So as an example, you can find the substring `"http"` to be replaced by `"https"`

```dos
@echo off
set "NewStr=https"
set "InFile=%~dp0%~n0_InputTest.txt"
set "OutPutFile=%~dp0%~n0_OutPutTest.txt"
If Exist "%InFile%" Del "%InFile%"
If Not Exist "%InFile%" Call :CreateExampleInputFile
Call :FindReplace "" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%"
pause
set "OldStr=http"
Call :FindReplace "%OldStr%" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%" "%OutPutFile%"
Start "" "%OutPutFile%"
Pause & Exit /b
::**************************************************************
:FindReplace <OldStr> <NewStr> <InFile> <OutPutFile>
REM -- Prepare the Command Processor --
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
::FindReplace - parses a File line by line and replaces a substring"
::syntax: FindReplace <OldStr> <NewStr> <InFile> <OutPutFile>
::          OldStr [in] - string to be replaced
::          NewStr [in] - string to replace with
::          InFile [in] - file to be parsed
::          OutFile[out] - New output file
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
(
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
        set "line=%%B"
        if defined line (
            call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
            for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
        ) ELSE echo.
    )
)>%4
Exit /b
::**************************************************************
:CreateExampleInputFile
(
    echo http://www.hyperdebrid.com
    echo http://www.fakirdebrid.net
    echo http://www.keepfiles.fr
    echo http://www.4shared.com 
    echo http://1fichier.com
    echo http://www.mega.co.nz
    echo http://www.mediafire.com
    echo http://www.uploaded.net
    echo http://www.oboom.com
    echo http://www.letitbit.net
    echo http://www.keep2share.cc
    echo http://alfafile.net
    echo http://www.bigfile.to
    echo http://www.dailymotion.com
    echo http://www.datafile.com
    echo http://www.Depfile.com
    echo http://www.Dropbox.com
    echo http://www.Extmatrix.com
    echo http://www.Fboom.me
    echo http://www.Filefactory.com
    echo http://www.Filesmonster.com
    echo http://www.Fshare.vn
    echo http://www.Keep2share.com
    echo http://www.Mega.nz
    echo http://www.Rapidgator.net
    echo http://www.Scribd.com
    echo http://www.Soundcloud.com
    echo http://www.Speedyshare.com
    echo http://www.Turbobit.net
    echo http://www.Vimeo.com
 )>"%InFile%"
 ::**************************************************************
```

Comment: Nice file! how do you get it to be so colorful?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you with your problem.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

CALL :Brains "Hello" "Goodbye" "input.txt"
GOTO :EOF

:Brains
IF "%~1"=="" (FINDSTR/R "^::" "%~f0"
    PAUSE
    GOTO :EOF)
(FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS=]" %%A IN ('FIND /N /V ""^<%3') DO (IF "%%~B" EQU "" (
            ECHO=) ELSE (SET "line=%%B"
            CALL ECHO=%%line:%~1=%~2%%)))>"newfile.txt"
PAUSE
```

Comment: Why a downvote? I tested it and it works totally fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

:SetVar
call :Brains "Hello" "Goodbye" "input.txt"
GOTO :Brains

:Brains
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.
)
PAUSE
```

One last try cause I am a friendly person that wants to help... Take this code, place it in a batch-file and place the batch-file in the same directory as `input.txt` . Place text in that text-file, save it and run the script. It should echo all lines that are written in the document and it changes Hello to Goodbye **in the output** as well.

Comment: What O.S are you running?

Comment: @Malkavian Windows 7

Comment: Doesn't work I get blank cmd window. when I looked closer I found the error  `The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.` I am running windows 10 by the way.

Comment: Do you try to change regex characters, more specifically backslashes?